# Is there such thing as "main" OS in case of type 1 hypervisor?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hypervisor

When we work with type 2 hypervisors it is very easy to say which OS is the main one. For example, if you install some type 2 hypervisor on Win 7, and launch Win 95 inside this hypervisor, the main OS will be Win 7. The conception is obvious.

[image]

However, it's not so obvious with type 1 hypervisors. I never worked with them before.

You have few operating systems on top the hypervisor. So... Which one of these OSs will be the **main one**? How this question is resolved? And probably (just a guess) there is no such thing as "main OS" in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that "main" operating system is a defined term.

A type 2 hypervisor is an extension to an operating system, which is known as the **host** operating system when guest operating systems are running on top of it. A host operating system runs directly on the hardware and needs to have specific code to interact with the hardware (e.g. the NIC, the disk, etc.) and provide abstractions to user-level programs. The hypervisor simply extends the functionality of the host operating system to allow guest operating systems to run on top (e.g. when the guest operating system wants to write to the hard drive, the hypervisor translates this request to a form that the host OS can understand so that the host OS can make the disk access).

A type 1 hypervisor runs directly on the hardware without an operating system. A type 1 hypervisor is basically just a stripped down operating system with the functionality necessary to allow guest operating systems to run on top. When the guest needs to write to disk or do some other privileged operation, the type 1 hypervisor receives the request and acts on it. Perhaps the type 1 hypervisor is what you would consider the "main" OS? Regardless, I would avoid using that term.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the way Hyper-V is used. It is disabled or enabled in Win 10 or 11 (except Home distribution). I think these pictures above are little unfortunate regarding what happens if you disable/enable Hyper-V in your main Win OS. I think it safe to say that in that moment your main Win OS basically becomes the Hypervisor itself, right? But of course, it needs to benoted that the Hypervisor Type 1 does not need to be a full OS. Like you wrote, it may be only stripped down OS.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that the "main" OS would be the Hypervisor software itself, as it runs directly on the hardware and supports the virtual operating systems, as well as boots on system startup.